# If $ \sum\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges, then $\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}$ converges to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm studying Strong Law of Large Numbers proof, and I think above statement is a non-trivial one, so I want to know whether the above statement is true or not.

Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: @K.Hoffmann No, they are not the same. One is $\frac{a_1}{1}+\frac{a_2}{2}+\frac{a_3}{3}+...$, another is the sequence $\frac{a_1}{1}, \frac{a_1+a_2}{2}, \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{3},...$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement is true. This is [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma).

If $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is an infinite sequence of real numbers such that 
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty x_m = s
$$ 
exists and is finite, then we have for all $0<b_1 \leq b_2 \leq b_3 \leq \ldots$ and $b_n \to \infty$ that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n b_kx_k = 0.
$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} = a > 0$, and let $\mu$ be a natural number. Then if $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ so that $m>N$ implies $|a-\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{a_n}{n}|< \varepsilon/4$. Then if $M > m > N$, you can show
$$|\sum_{n=m+1}^M \frac{a_n}{n}| < \varepsilon/2 $$
Now we have, for each $M=\mu m+k$ (where $0\leq k < \mu$ and $m>N$), 
$$|A_M| = |\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_M}{M}| \leq |\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_m}{M}|+|\frac{a_{m+1}+...+a_M}{M}| \leq $$
$$\frac{1}{\mu}|\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{a_n}{n}| + |\sum_{n=m+1}^M \frac{a_n}{n}| < \frac{a+\varepsilon/4}{\mu}+\varepsilon/2 < \frac{a}{\mu}+\varepsilon$$
Since this works for all $\varepsilon>0$, we have that $\lim_{M\to\infty} |A_M| \leq \frac{a}{\mu}$ for all $\mu \in \Bbb{N}$, so $\lim_{M\to\infty} A_M = 0$.

EDIT: This only works if the $a_i$ eventually all have the same sign. See comments.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\lvert\sum_{n=m+1}^{M}\frac{a_n}{n}\rvert\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2},$$ with the absolute value sign?

Comment: Yes, I'll fix that. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is better to choose $N$ so that when $M\gt m\gt N$, both $|a-\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{a_n}{n}|< \varepsilon/4$ and $|\sum_{n=m+1}^M \frac{a_n}{n}| < \varepsilon/2$ are satisfied, with the first inequality allowed by definition of convergent series, and the second inequality allowed by [Cauchy's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test). That way, we don't have to show that the second inequality holds.

Comment: I am not sure if the inequality $$|\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_m}{M}|+|\frac{a_{m+1}+...+a_M}{M}| \leq \frac{1}{\mu}|\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{a_n}{n}| + |\sum_{n=m+1}^M \frac{a_n}{n}|$$ is true. Could you prove it?

Comment: For the second term, you're just making all of the denominators smaller, which makes the whole sum bigger. For the first, note that $\frac{a_i}{M}\leq \frac{a_i}{\mu m} = \frac{1}{\mu} \frac{a_i}{m}\leq \frac{1}{\mu}\frac{a_i}{i}$ (since $i\leq m$). I suppose this assumes that $a_i \geq 0$, but since I first assumed that $a>0$ it isn't difficult to modify the series so that each $a_i\geq 0$

Comment: Your argument seems to depend on that all $a_i$'s are of the same sign. For example, if $a_1=-1, a_2=2$, then $\frac{1}{2}=|\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}|\gt |a_1+\frac{a_2}{2}|=0$.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I'll edit the post.